# Problem with multiple feature selection

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, features, select

In an attempt to retrieve all features (point geometry) that fall in a selected polygon, I get the error `this.layer.addFeatures is not a function`. My code is as shown below:

```
function createWFSVector(map, WFS_HOST) {
var population = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Population Vector", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version: "1.1.0",
        url: WFS_HOST,
        featureType: "population_layer",
        featureNS: "pe_ns",
        srsName: "EPSG:4326"
    })
});

addMapControls(map, population);
map.addLayers([population]);
}

function addMapControls(map, wfsLayer) {
var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([wfsLayer], {
    box: true,
    multiple: true,
    onSelect: addSelected,
    onUnselect: clearSelected
});
map.addControl(select);
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar(select));
select.activate();
}

function addSelected(feature) {
selectedFeatures.push(feature);
}

function clearSelected(feature) {
selectedFeatures = [];
}
```

I can't seem to spot the problem with my code. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made mistake: `new OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar(select)` should be `new OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar(wfsLayer)` in your case.

Comment: You are right. Its not generating the error now. Now I'll have to try the other aspects; whether it actually retrieves the feature.

Comment: I had to confirm that it works. And, sorry it took me a while to do that. Thanks loads. It was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try to take out select and population from addMapControls and createWFSVector function respectively. and try this code:

```
var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(population, {
    box: true,
    clickout: false,
    hover: false,
    multiple: false,
    onSelect: function(f){
         var sltedFeature = population.selectedFeatures;
         alert(sltedFeature.length)       
                          },
    onUnselect: clearSelected
});
map.addControl(select);
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar(select));
select.activate();
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks. I've done this, but the problem still persists. Still working on it. I hope to land a solution soon.